# python: function call from within a class

Tags: python, kivy

This is a sample program to display "Hello" or "Good-bye" when you push the button 1 or 2, simplified from my real program.
What I want to do is to execute function btn1() and display "Hello" when the program starts, without pushing the button 1.
What lines of code and where should I add?
When I put "Greetings().btn1()" in class Greetings, error: "name Greetings is not defined" occured.  Then I put the same command after def build(self) in class GreetingApp, but nothing happened.

In main.py,

```
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout  
from kivy.properties import StringProperty  

class Greetings(BoxLayout):
    greeting=StringProperty()  

    def btn1(self):  
        self.greeting='Hello.'  

    def btn2(self):  
        self.greeting='Good-bye.'  

class GreetingApp(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return Greetings()  

GreetingApp().run()
```

And in greeting.kv,

```
#: import main main

Greetings:  
<Greetings>:

    orientation: "vertical"  
    Label:  
        text: root.greeting  
    BoxLayout:  
        orientation: "horizontal"  
        Button:  
            text: '1'  
            on_press: root.btn1()  
        Button:  
            text: '2'  
            on_press: root.btn2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `btn1` before returning root widget:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<Greetings>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Label:
        text: root.greeting
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        Button:
            text: '1'
            on_press: root.btn1()
        Button:
            text: '2'
            on_press: root.btn2()
''')


class Greetings(BoxLayout):
    greeting = StringProperty()

    def btn1(self):
        self.greeting = 'Hello.' 

    def btn2(self): 
        self.greeting = 'Good-bye.' 

class GreetingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Greetings()
        root.btn1()

        return root

GreetingApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method runs every time you create an instance of a class.
So what ever you want to do in creation time of the object, you can put in `__init__`. Initiate the object.
Put this in your Greetings class.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Greetings, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.btn1()
```

Then you call it when you create the object.

Comment: Your code also works fine. Thanks.  I'll try to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @user9037109 updated with a bit more explanation. Tell me if it needs more explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your additional explanation.  I just wondered why first argument (Greetings) is necessary.  They say explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: and in python 3 it is optional. Thenk you for everything.

Comment: @user9037109 You are wellcome. Yea thats how you call super in python 2.7. I couldnt see that you were using python 3.